# Category not found returns 200 OK, I need 404

Tags: templates, template-override

My website has been upgraded from a custom written 1.5 template and I need to run a link checked over it to discover broken links.

For one url:

```
/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=2639&lang=en
```

The page returns a HTTP 200 OK header, however the page contains: "Error Category not found"

In /libraries/legacy/view/category.php:131 there is clearly code to return a 404 error:

```
return JError::raiseError(404, JText::_('JGLOBAL_CATEGORY_NOT_FOUND'));
```

Am I doing something wrong in my template?

Comment: Please check this post: http://www.itoctopus.com/the-right-way-to-handle-404s-in-joomla on the right way to handle 404s in Joomla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an error.php in your template generating a header 404 when a page is not found?

My error.php contains the following information:

```
<?php
/*
 * @package     perfecttemplate
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) Perfect Web Team / perfectwebteam.nl
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 3 or later
 */

// No direct access.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

if (($this->error->getCode()) == '404')
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    switch (JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag())
    {
        #case 'en-GB':
        #   echo file_get_contents(JURI::base().'en/404');
        #   break;

        default:
            // get Joomla! article with menu item alias = 404
            echo file_get_contents(JURI::base().'404');
    }
    exit;
}

if (($this->error->getCode()) == '403')
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");
    switch (JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag())
    {
        #case 'en-GB':
        #   echo file_get_contents(JURI::base().'en/404');
        #   break;

        default:
            // get Joomla! article with menu item alias = 403
            echo file_get_contents(JURI::base().'403');
    }
    exit;
}
```

If a certain error occurs the header will respond with it's corresponding reply. 
In my case only 403 or 404.